# how to receive incoming data from tcp socket

Tags: sockets

I need to catch incoming data from tcp socket at any time and then execute a python script on my Raspberry Pi. How do I do that?   I hope that you understand what i need to do.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on the www to do what you want.  Perhaps try one and let us know if you have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered putting the TCP socket receive code inside your Python script?

Or you can just write another Python script that does a socket create, socket listen, and socket receive before calling your other Python script.

Here is some of the code to do this from http://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Connect the socket to the port where the server is listening
# substitute the TCP port you want to listen on for 10000 below
server_address = ('', 10000)

print >>sys.stderr, 'connecting to %s port %s' % server_address
sock.connect(server_address)

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    # Wait for a connection
    print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

        # Receive the data in small chunks and retransmit it
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            print >>sys.stderr, 'received "%s"' % data
            if data:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'Data received - starting other Python script'
                <insert Python code to start other Python script>
            else:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break

    finally:
        # Clean up the connection
        connection.close()
```

Comment: thanks. this is what i looking for. how to make it running background so that can listen from port at any time.

Comment: @hddman see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-line-run-in-background/

Comment: had to be bind rather than connect!